# How to import functions from NPM modules in Fable?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to use the NPM package [normalize-wheel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-wheel) in a Fable project.

I've confirmed that the package has been downloaded to the `node-modules` folder.

In line with the [documentation](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html) and [this article](https://medium.com/@zaid.naom/f-interop-with-javascript-in-fable-the-complete-guide-ccc5b896a59f) I'm using the following F# code:

```
type INormalizedWheel =
    abstract member pixelX: float
    abstract member pixelY: float
    abstract member spinX: float
    abstract member spinY: float

[<Import("normalizeWheel", "normalize-wheel")>]
let normalizeWheel (we: React.WheelEvent) : INormalizedWheel = jsNative

...

let x = normalizeWheel wheelEvent
```

However, whenever the final line is reached, a JS error message `"Object(...) is not a function"` is thrown.  In the debugger, the type of `normalizeWheel` is shown as `undefined`.

I guess the importing is not working, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at normalize-wheel/index.js

```
module.exports = require('./src/normalizeWheel.js');
```

This tells us that there isn't any function named normalizeWheel (otherwise it would be module.exports.normalizeWheel = ...). This means that we need to import the default function. This can be done like this:

```
[<Import("default", "normalize-wheel")>]
let normalizeWheel (we: React.WheelEvent) : INormalizedWheel = jsNative

// Or
let normalizeWheel (we: React.WheelEvent) : INormalizedWheel = importDefault "normalize-wheel"
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  One of the downsides of Fable's excellence is that I don't know any JavaScript.